# RoR3 HABTM Checkboxes Not Saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datamapper

In the console, my query works just fine:

```
u = Radcheck.get(23)
g = Group.get(16) 
@relationship = u.radgroups << g
```

And a save writes to the db.

When I try and do so in my rails view, it doesn't save.

```
<%= check_box_tag "radcheck[groupnames][]", group.id, @radcheck.radgroups.include?(group) %>
```

Im using datamapper, and have the radcheck model setup like this:

```
has n, :radusergroup, :child_key => [:username], :parent_key => [:username]
has n, :radgroups, :through => :radusergroup, :model => 'Group'
```

My radcheck table contains the columns username and groupname

Any suggestions?

-- Update --

Further to answer below, I've added an id to the radusergroup table (my join table). This currently looks like this:

```
+-------------+---------------------------+----------+----+
| username    | groupname                 | priority | id |
+-------------+---------------------------+----------+----+
| hcTTm       | 3600                      |        1 |  1 |
| FpKS4       | 3600                      |        1 |  2 |
| jenny       | Disabled-Users            |        1 |  3 |
| silver      | silver                    |        1 |  4 |
| shushQb     | 30-minutes                |        0 |  5 |
| jenny       | silver                    |        1 |  6 |
+-------------+---------------------------+----------+----+
```

This is driving me to distraction now

I have exactly the right information in my models and can only assume it's the save that's the issue?

Comment: Suggest you up your accept% by deleting some of your older questions (not the November ones) that never got answers (page 2 of your questions).

Comment: Thanks I'll do so. Not really sure why that affects this question though?

Answer (score 2):

change to use groupname_ids

```
<%= check_box_tag "radcheck[groupname_ids][]", group.id, @radcheck.radgroups.include?(group) %>
```

Also It's best to stop using HABTM.  use has_many :through

EXAMPLE USER has many roles through user_roles

```
class User 
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, :through => :user_roles
end
class UserRole
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :user
end
class Role
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, :through => :user_roles
end
```

and add an ID to the join table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sadly that's not working either. In my model, I'm using has many through - maybe that's the issue. What's the syntax for a has many through rel?

Comment: For example...  for a user class...  has_many :user_roles   THEN has_many :roles, :through => :user_roles  |||  BUT you need an id field in the join table.  You also need a class UserRole with belongs_to :role AND belongs_to :user

Comment: Despite my best efforts, it's still not working. I'm assuming now this is a datamapper issue, not an issue with the code. I can't even see the insert happening in the logs. Have updated question.